# Dependency Injection in Class Library in ASP.NET Core 2

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core Class Library that depends on dependency injection in the project that references the dll. But when I try to get the service, the service is always null.

This is the only design I have come up so far that should work, since I guess I can't set up dependency services directly in a Class Library.

**Class Library**:

```
public interface IHtmlResourceLocalizer
{
    string Get(string cultureCode, string name);
    string Get(CultureInfo culture, string name);
}

public class HtmlResourceLocalizer : IHtmlResourceLocalizer
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _env;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _context;

    public HtmlResourceLocalizer(IHostingEnvironment env, IHttpContextAccessor context)
    {
        _env = env;
        _context = context;
    }

    public string Get(string cultureCode, string name) { return Get(new CultureInfo(cultureCode), name); }

    public string Get(CultureInfo culture, string name)
    {
        string result = string.Empty, filename = name + "." + culture.Parent.Name + ".cshtml";
        string path = Path.Combine(this.Env.ContentRootPath, "Views", "Resources", filename);

        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            IRazorViewEngine engine = _context.HttpContext.Features.Get<IRazorViewEngine>();
            ITempDataProvider temp = _context.HttpContext.Features.Get<ITempDataProvider>();

            ViewRenderUtility util = new ViewRenderUtility(engine, temp, _context.HttpContext.RequestServices);

            result = util.ViewToString(filename, null).Result;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Could not find file \"" + path + "\"");
        }

        return result;
    }

    public IHostingEnvironment Env { get { return _env; } }
}
```

**Startup in the project that references the Class Library**:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
    services.AddSingleton<IHtmlResourceLocalizer, HtmlResourceLocalizer>();
    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
    services.AddSingleton<IRazorViewEngine, RazorViewEngine>();
    services.AddSingleton<AppHelper>();

    services.AddMvc()
        .AddViewLocalization(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
        .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
}
```

**View**:

```
@inject IHtmlResourceLocalizer _local

@Html.Raw(_local.Get("no-NB", "Tech"))
```

Comment: Can you direct us to where the error line is?

Comment: the error occures in this line ViewRenderUtility util = new ViewRenderUtility(engine, temp, _context.HttpContext.RequestServices); in the class library. variable engine and temp are always null

Comment: You registered `HtmlResourceLocalizer` twice in `ConfigureServices` (as singleton in line 2 and scoped in last line). What's the reason of this?

Comment: Just a little typo, I've updated the question